# Recover after "kill 0"

Tags: linux, shell, sh, kill-process

I have a script that invokes `kill 0`.  I want to invoke that script from another script, and have the outer script continue to execute. (`kill 0` sends a signal, defaulting to `SIGTERM`, to every process in the process group of the calling process; see `man 2 kill`.)

`kill0.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

kill 0
```

`caller.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo BEFORE
./kill0.sh
echo AFTER
```

The current behavior is:

```
$ ./caller.sh
BEFORE
Terminated
$
```

How can I modify `caller.sh` so it prints `AFTER` after invoking `kill0.sh`?

Modifying `kill0.sh` is not an option. Assume that `kill0.sh` might read from stdin and write to stdout and/or stderr before invoking `kill 0`, and I don't want to interfere with that. I still want the `kill 0` command to kill the `kill0.sh` process itself; I just don't want it to kill the caller as well.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 x86_64, and `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash`. That shouldn't matter, and I prefer answers that don't depend on that.

This is of course a simplified version of a larger set of scripts, so I'm at some risk of having an XY problem, but I think that a solution to the problem as stated here should let me solve the actual problem. (I have a wrapper script that invokes a specified command, capturing and displaying its output, with some other bells and whistles.)

Comment: Maybe (temporally) ignore SIGTERM in caller.sh?

Comment: @wildplasser: Good idea, but it changes the behavior of `kill0.sh`. I still want the `kill 0` command to kill the script itself, but if I add `trap '' 15` to `caller.sh`, `kill0.sh` continues to execute after the `kill 0` command.

Comment: You mean: kill0.sh should commit suicide, but *not* kill its father? (eudipus-protector;-)

Answer (score 1):

#### One solution

You need to trap the signal in the parent, but enable it in the child.  So a script like `run-kill0.sh` could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo BEFORE
trap '' TERM
(trap 15; exec ./kill0.sh)
echo AFTER
```

The first `trap` disables the TERM signal.  The second `trap` in the sub-shell re-enables the signal (using the signal number instead of the name — see below) before running the `kill0.sh` script.  Using `exec` is a minor optimization — you can omit it and it will work the same.

#### Digression on obscure syntactic details

Why `15` instead of `TERM` in the sub-shell?  Because when I tested it with `TERM` instead of `15`, I got:

```
$ sh -x run-kill0.sh
+ echo BEFORE
BEFORE
+ trap '' TERM
+ trap TERM
trap: usage: trap [-lp] [arg signal_spec ...]
+ echo AFTER
AFTER
$
```

When I used `15` in place of `TERM` (twice), I got:

```
$ sh -x run-kill0.sh
+ echo BEFORE
BEFORE
+ trap '' 15
+ trap 15
+ exec ./kill0.sh
Terminated: 15
+ echo AFTER
AFTER
$
```

Using `TERM` in place of the first `15` would also work.

#### Bash documentation on `trap`

Studying the Bash manual for [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) shows:

> `trap [-lp] [arg] [sigspec …]`
>
> The commands in *arg* are to be read and executed when the shell receives signal *sigspec*. If *arg* is absent (and there is a single *sigspec*) or equal to ‘-’, each specified signal’s disposition is reset to the value it had when the shell was started.

#### A second solution

The second sentence is the key: `trap - TERM` should (and empirically does) work.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo BEFORE
trap '' TERM
(trap - TERM; exec ./kill0.sh)
echo AFTER
```

Running that yields:

```
$ sh -x run-kill0.sh
+ echo BEFORE
BEFORE
+ trap '' TERM
+ trap - TERM
+ exec ./kill0.sh
Terminated: 15
+ echo AFTER
AFTER
$
```

I've just re-remembered why I use numbers and not names (but my excuse is that the shell — it wasn't Bash in those days — didn't recognize signal names when I learned it).

#### POSIX documentation for `trap`

However, in Bash's defense, the POSIX spec for [`trap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) says:

> If the first operand is an unsigned decimal integer, the shell shall treat all operands as conditions, and shall reset each condition to the default value. Otherwise, if there are operands, the first is treated as an action and the remaining as conditions.
>
> If action is '-', the shell shall reset each condition to the default value. If action is null ( "" ), the shell shall ignore each specified condition if it arises.

This is clearer than the Bash documentation, IMO.  It states why `trap 15` works. There's also a minor glitch in the presentation.  The synopsis says (on one line):

> ```
> trap n [condition...]trap [action condition...]
> ```

It should say (on two lines):

`trap`*`n`*`[`*`condition`*`...]`
`trap [`*`action condition`*`...]`